# How to scroll collectionview horizontal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I'm using camera and gallery to take image and add it to collection view, i want to add image to collection view to horizontal direction only so i add image to array and change collection frame to increase collection view width increase, but collection is not scroll to horizontal as i increase height of it, so what is way to do it?

Here is my code :

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[arrayPictures addObject:image];
_collPic.frame = CGRectMake(0, _collPic.frame.origin.y, arrayPictures.count*76, 76);
[_collPic reloadData];
```

Comment: `[yourFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];` use this

Comment: i set direction in storyboard.

Comment: 1. You don't need to change the frame.width of the collectionview fix it max to parent view. 2. Adjust your cell size to adjust within the collectionview you can do from storyboard. 3. You can test if the cell are properly aligned horizontal by adding more items through storyboard, you can view collectionview how it looks in design time only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set it through property Inspector

[image]

Or you can set programatically with

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init ];
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 6;
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(55, 55);
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

---

```
blendEffectCollectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 95, 320, 60) collectionViewLayout:layout];
[blendEffectCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[blendEffectCollectionView setDelegate:self];

[blendEffectCollectionView registerClass:[BlendModeCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[blendEffectCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[self.view addSubview:blendEffectCollectionView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width based on the number of the pictures. It should be set to a reasonable value.

Try

```
_collPic.frame = CGRectMake(0, _collPic.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.width, 76);
```

And set the scrooll direction of collection view to horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

**try this line of code in view did load**

```
[yourCollectionView setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
```